# Parse Json String to object

Tags: apex, json

Can anyone help me understand on how to parse the response in to a JSON object from string.

```
String s = [{"id":"12345","Account":"31338","name":"Accounttest","subaccounts":[{"id":"39658"}]}]
```

I'm generating the above string Using JSON.createGenerator.

Comment: to handle responses normally I'm using JSONParser class https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm

Answer (score 0):

You say you want an Object so it is pretty easy:

```
var result = JSON.parse(s);
```

Or do you mean you want it to be parsed into a class or object in apex:

```
Map<String,Object> result = JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
```

Into a class You can use [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com) to generate the class:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Subaccounts {
        public String id;
    }

    public String id;
    public String Account;
    public String name;
    public List<Subaccounts> subaccounts;


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

If none if this is what you are looking for, could could you clarify your question

Comment: Do we have JSON.Parse method in APEX?

Comment: @cartman - No, only serialize and deserialize, thats why I put the latter part of my answer for, in case you wanted to do it in apex. You could also use the JSONParser methods but it is overkill for what you are doing here.